# tomcat trace request - why does the server respond with a 403

Tags: tomcat

Newbie to tomact here.
I've deployed a java application with an embedded tomcat server (8.0) on an ubunto server, and it's working fine over HTTPS.

I'm getting a 403 response for one of the API endpoints defined there only for a specific device*.

Naturally, I want to understand what's the reason I'm getting this 403.
I configured tomcat's access log to record a bunch of things, as explained [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve).

However, I want to understand *why* tomcat chooses to respond with a 403;

1. Is there a way to see a request trace that'll say why the server responded with a 403?
2. Failing that - is there a way to log the full request and full response (i.e body + headers)?

*more info (probably not that relevant): I'm trying to establish a web socket connection over wss; this works fine in most cases (desktop browsers, mobile browsers), except for a cordova hybrid app on an ipad (haven't tested on an android device yet).

Comment: *"is there a way to log the full request and full response (i.e body + headers)?"* You mean like `wget --debug --server-response -O - $URL`? Though of course that will likely pretty much just tell you what you already know...

Comment: yeah, i guess so; so I guess what I'd want is some sort of tracing from tomcat that indicates why it chose to reply with 403